# SQL Server 2008 Pivot Data

Tags: sql-server-2008

If I have four columns called `Person1`, `Person2`, `Person3` and `Value`.

Is it possible to pivot all three Person columns into just one like below(?):

```
Person Value
-------------------
Person1 10

Person1 50 

Person2 60

Person3 0
```

I am using `SQL Server 2008.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The process of transforming multiple columns into multiple rows is called [UNPIVOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):

```
select person, val
from yourtable
unpivot
(
  val
  for person in (Person1, Person2, Person3)
) unpiv;
```

This could also be written using a UNION ALL query:

```
select 'person1' as person, person1 as val
from yourtable
union all
select 'person2' as person, person2 as val
from yourtable
union all
select 'person3' as person, person3 as val
from yourtable;
```

Since you are using SQL Server 2008, you could also use CROSS APPLY with a VALUES clause:

```
select c.person, c.val
from yourtable
cross apply
(
  values
  ('person1', person1),
  ('person2', person2),
  ('person3', person3)
) c (person, val)
```

Comment: Hi bluefeet,
Thanks for your reply.

Using the UNION ALL method, how would you discount rows where there is a NULL value in any of the Person columns?

Comment: @user2493043 The UNPIVOT function will exclude an null values, the UNION ALL will show all values including `null`.